# PHP combining two URL query string using two GET methods

Tags: php, url, get, query-string

I have two forms with a GET method. when I submit the 1st form I get this URL

`http://127.0.0.1/astronomy/student_enrollment.php?class_name_data=1&classNameGetDetails=`

and when I submit the 2nd form that also had a GET method. my URL changed to this

`http://127.0.0.1/astronomy/student_enrollment.php?class_name_for_enrollment=Planet&sy_for_enrollment=2012-2013&sy_for_enrollment=45&number_of_student_enrolled=&time_schedule_student=Monday+to+Friday+8%3A00-9%3A00&generateFields=Generate`

the first query string was removed and replaced by the 2nd query string

I want my URL to look like this

`http://127.0.0.1/astronomy/student_enrollment.php?class_name_data=1&classNameGetDetails=&class_name_for_enrollment=Planet&sy_for_enrollment=2012-2013&sy_for_enrollment=45&number_of_student_enrolled=&time_schedule_student=Monday+to+Friday+8%3A00-9%3A00&generateFields=Generate`

The two query strings will combine with a separator of `&` and not `?`. how will I do this?

this is my code

```
<div class="enrollmentContent">
    <div class="classNameChoices">
    <label>Choose Class Name</label>
    <form action="" method="get">

        <select name="class_name_data">
            <?php
            $table = "classes";
            $data = array(
            'teacher_id' => $session_id
            );
            $class_name_query = show_filtered_rows($table, $data);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($class_name_query)){
                $id = $rows['id'];
                $class_name = $rows['class_name'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $class_name; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="classNameGetDetails" value="" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['classNameGetDetails'])){
            $data2 = array(
            'id' => $_GET['class_name_data'],
            'teacher_id' => $session_id
            );
            $class_name_data_query = show_filtered_rows($table, $data2);
            $rows_class = mysql_fetch_array($class_name_data_query);
    ?>
    <div class="classDetailsByClassName">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['class_name']; ?>" name="class_name_for_enrollment" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['school_year_from']."-".$rows_class['school_year_to']; ?>" name="sy_for_enrollment" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['enrollees']; ?>" name="sy_for_enrollment" />
        <label>Class Name <span><?php echo $rows_class['class_name']; ?></span></label>
        <label>SY <span><?php echo $rows_class['school_year_from']."-".$rows_class['school_year_to']; ?></span></label>
        <label>Maximum No. of Enrollees <span><?php echo $rows_class['enrollees']; ?></span></label>
        <div class="registerDetails">
            <div>
                <label>Number of students to enroll</label>
                <div><input type="number" name="number_of_student_enrolled" value=""/></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Schedule</label>
                <div>
                    <select name='time_schedule_student'>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 8:00-9:00">Monday to Friday 8:00-9:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 10:00-11:00">Monday to Friday 10:00-11:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 1:00-2:00">Monday to Friday 1:00-2:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 2:00-3:00">Monday to Friday 2:00-3:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 9:00-10:00">Monday to Friday 9:00-10:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 3:00-4:00">Monday to Friday 3:00-4:00</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" name="generateFields" value="Generate" /></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="enrollmentFields">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['generateFields'])){
            echo $_GET['class_name_for_enrollment'];
        }
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

and my function

```
function show_filtered_rows($table, $data){
    foreach($data as $fields=>$field_data){
        $show_data[] = "`".$fields."` = '".$field_data."'";
    }
    return mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$show_data));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the values of your first form into your second form as hidden values.

```php
<input type="hidden" name="class_name_data" value="<?php echo $_GET['class_name_data']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="classNameGetDetails" value="<?php echo $_GET['classNameGetDetails']; ?>" />
```

Here is the full code with the 2 above lines added. The PHP function doesn't change.

```php
<div class="enrollmentContent">
    <div class="classNameChoices">
    <label>Choose Class Name</label>
    <form action="" method="get">

        <select name="class_name_data">
            <?php
            $table = "classes";
            $data = array(
            'teacher_id' => $session_id
            );
            $class_name_query = show_filtered_rows($table, $data);
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($class_name_query)){
                $id = $rows['id'];
                $class_name = $rows['class_name'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $class_name; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="classNameGetDetails" value="" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['classNameGetDetails'])){
            $data2 = array(
            'id' => $_GET['class_name_data'],
            'teacher_id' => $session_id
            );
            $class_name_data_query = show_filtered_rows($table, $data2);
            $rows_class = mysql_fetch_array($class_name_data_query);
    ?>
    <div class="classDetailsByClassName">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="class_name_data" value="<?php echo $_GET['class_name_data']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="classNameGetDetails" value="<?php echo $_GET['classNameGetDetails']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['class_name']; ?>" name="class_name_for_enrollment" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['school_year_from']."-".$rows_class['school_year_to']; ?>" name="sy_for_enrollment" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rows_class['enrollees']; ?>" name="sy_for_enrollment" />
        <label>Class Name <span><?php echo $rows_class['class_name']; ?></span></label>
        <label>SY <span><?php echo $rows_class['school_year_from']."-".$rows_class['school_year_to']; ?></span></label>
        <label>Maximum No. of Enrollees <span><?php echo $rows_class['enrollees']; ?></span></label>
        <div class="registerDetails">
            <div>
                <label>Number of students to enroll</label>
                <div><input type="number" name="number_of_student_enrolled" value=""/></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Schedule</label>
                <div>
                    <select name='time_schedule_student'>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 8:00-9:00">Monday to Friday 8:00-9:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 10:00-11:00">Monday to Friday 10:00-11:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 1:00-2:00">Monday to Friday 1:00-2:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 2:00-3:00">Monday to Friday 2:00-3:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 9:00-10:00">Monday to Friday 9:00-10:00</option>
                        <option value="Monday to Friday 3:00-4:00">Monday to Friday 3:00-4:00</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" name="generateFields" value="Generate" /></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="enrollmentFields">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['generateFields'])){
            echo $_GET['class_name_for_enrollment'];
        }
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need set value for your hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="class_name_data" value="<?php echo $_GET['class_name_data']" />
```

and put the your 2st form.